# Django/Python version of Premailer?

Tags: python, django, email

I'm looking to automate the sending of multi-part emails. Now I need to format the text accordingly for both HTML and plaintext versions. [Premailer](http://premailer.dialect.ca/) seems pretty awesome. I especially like how it handles the plaintext version.

Anyone know of anything comparable written for Django/Python?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/premailer

There is also a barely-supported [Django Premailer](https://github.com/alexhayes/django-premailer) app, for ideas.